# How to extend a parent's property in child

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I have the following code:

```
class Table {
    get pagination () {
        return {
            get item () {
                return {
                    log (s : string) {
                        console.log(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class TableWithFirst extends Table {
    get pagination () {
        return {
            ...super.pagination,
            get first () {
                this.item.log("first");
                return "first";
            }
        }
    }
}
const t = new TableWithFirst();
t.pagination.first
```

and with this code, I get the error below:

```
[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
[ERR]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'log')
```

How do I add `first` getter to `pagination`? Is moving that logic into a class the only way?

Comment: This question is more about JavaScript internal mechanics rather than typescript

Comment: @captain-yossarian Actually, it is a TypeScript problem. The code works fine in JS, but for some reason [TS compiles it to use `Object.assign` for the spread syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFNoG8CwAoavoHNkAXaABzHwEsA7MIyge2ugAoBKdbPb6AJ2ICuvZphw9xhEpSLIAtqw6jxyvPyJCRXFdtwgG+VjABc0CEV418irTtvRgTCAxQA6PfhYQ2Abht2eAL5+dkFiOqEqEXihoaCQMPBIyADq0gAWAGKUvGbQyAAeMtQAJgmIKJxhBMRkFDR0jMzslSpqGi22Ll0QAqTIvC7kVLT0TAA0wcqS0ABm2bnNSv64RGmUEC7Scm76LABEczlEez6TOm3C0Afzx75VkWfQUbgx2A7UuSQAvNDUyADucHKKXSWSO7DuREGdRGjRchzMQA) which causes the getter to fail

Comment: If you don't need to support older browsers you can change compilation target to `ES2018` so spread syntax won't be transpiled https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFNoG8BQ1vQObIBdoAHMXASwDswDyB7S6ACgEp0sdOAnQgVy8aZOwnPiLkCyALbM2QkQuw8C-QR0UboIOrmYwAXNAgEuVXHPWarwBhDooAdNtxMILANyWrwgL5erft6BCsHYfn6gkDDwSMgA6hIAFgBi5FzG0MgAHpKUACbRiCjsnGIkZFQ09IysJcI2lBkQyCAAZtAAvNAEieQQ-kp8AnWaDmMQvMTIXA6kFNS0DAA0A8JlrWkZtfLe2D19DhLSTjpMAEQb6QRnHquKyqrQF5vXnkGrodDhGA0ZRF2UZAAdzgRXiSVSV1YngIswqC2qDkuxiAA

Comment: @Bergi, nice catch

Comment: @AlekseyL. This is part of automated UI QA, so it won't need browser support. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @AlekseyL. hmm, I'm using testcafe and your recommendation didn't fix it. Must be a testcafe thing then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support older browsers you can change compilation target to ES2018 (or higher) so spread syntax won't be transpiled.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqYCMQFNoG8BQ1vQObIBdoAHMXASwDswDyB7S6ACgEp0sdOAnQgVy8aZOwnPiLkCyALbM2QkQuw8C-QR0UboIOrmYwAXNAgEuVXHPWarwBhDooAdNtxMILANyWrwgL5erft6BCsHYfn6gkDDwSMgA6hIAFgBi5FzG0MgAHpKUACbRiCjsnGIkZFQ09IysJcI2lBkQyCAAZtAAvNAEieQQ-kp8AnWaDmMQvMTIXA6kFNS0DAA0A8JlrWkZtfLe2D19DhLSTjpMAEQb6QRnHquKyqrQF5vXnkGrodDhGA0ZRF2UZAAdzgRXiSVSV1YngIswqC2qDkuxiAA)

---

Regarding TestCafe, [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402824/guides/concepts/typescript-and-coffeescript#customize-compiler-options) you can find how to customize typescript compiler options used by its runner (it won't pick up standard tsconfig file).